# Get a Content Type by Name (Title) using CSOM

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, client-object-model

I am applying a temporary fix to some CSOM code whilst a more permanent fix is given to me
   hence I want to create the equivalent of

```
 ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Contoso Documents").ContentTypes.GetByName("Contoso Sales Document")
```

or  even

```
   ctx.Web.ContentTypes.GetByName("Contoso Sales Document")
```

has anyone implemented this or do      traverse all the content types in a ContentTypeCollection and try to match the title string

Answer (score 6):

How to retrieve `Content Type` by name using CSOM (implemented as extension method):

```
public static class ContentTypeExtensions
{
    public static ContentType GetByName(this ContentTypeCollection cts, string name)
    {
        var ctx = cts.Context;
        ctx.Load(cts);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        return Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(cts, ct => ct.Name == name);
    }
}
```

Examples:

```
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(url))
{ 
     //1. get site level content type
     var siteContentType = ctx.Site.RootWeb.ContentTypes.GetByName("Document Set");

     //2. get web level content type
     var webContentType = ctx.Web.ContentTypes.GetByName(webContentTypeName);


     //3. get list level content type
     var listContentType = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle).ContentTypes.GetByName(listContentTypeName);

}
```

Comment: Thanks very much - I will  to create this extension method. Out of interest why aren't you needed to reference an SPWeb object.

Comment: That could be a potential performance bottleneck as the while collection is fetched from the server. Reconsidering getting content type by ID might work much better.

Comment: Indeed it could affect the performance since all content types are retrieved from the server

Comment: In case it's tripping up anyone else: be aware of the difference between Web.ContentTypes (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.contenttypes.aspx) and Web.AvailableContentTypes (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.availablecontenttypes.aspx).