# How to get the list items from the content type name with CSOM SharePoint (C#)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

1 - I have to fetch all the items from the Calendar list who have the **specific content type**.
Eg. Content Type Name- "Test" this content type is assigne to multiple calendar lists.

2 - Also have to fetch the all list names and list items who have the specific content type with programmatically with C#.

Thanks!

Comment: maybe a good one: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/115499/get-a-content-type-by-name-title-using-csom

Comment: Hello Patrick,
Above link is not worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested this in a Console Application:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var context = new ClientContext(webUrl))
        {
            // 1 - Find items in a List by Content Type
            string contentTypeName = "Event";
            string listName = "Calendar 2";
            ListItemCollection items = FindItemsWithContentType(context, listName, contentTypeName);

            // 2 - Find all Lists that Contain Content Type and Items of that Content Type
            ListCollection siteLists = w.Lists;
            context.Load(siteLists);
            context.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (var list in siteLists)
            {
                if (CheckForContentTypeInList(context, list.Title, contentTypeName) == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(list.Title + " Contains Content Type");
                    items = FindItemsWithContentType(context, list.Title, contentTypeName);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static ListItemCollection FindItemsWithContentType(ClientContext context, string listName, string contentTypeName)
    {
        Web w = context.Web;

        var query = new CamlQuery()
        {
            ViewXml = String.Format("<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentType' /><Value Type='Computed'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>", contentTypeName)
        };

        List list = w.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
        ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);

        context.Load(items);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        return items;

    }

    private static bool CheckForContentTypeInList(ClientContext context, string listName, string contentTypeName) {

        Web w = context.Web;


        ContentTypeCollection contentTypes = w.Lists.GetByTitle(listName).ContentTypes;

        context.Load(contentTypes);
        context.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (ContentType ct in contentTypes)
        {
            if (ct.Name == contentTypeName)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```